# How to show menu item icon while showAsAction="never" is used?

Tags: android-actionbar

I want to show menu icon but it does not show icon. I have set showAsAction="never". How does it possible to show icon?

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

or

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```